# Selenium Webdriver | Unable to locate 'href' element

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate below link in Selenium Webdriver using Xpath and CSS.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="cspbItmA">
<a class="cspbItm" target="_parent" href="../isp_track.asp?PARENT_MENU=Customer Order">Find Order</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

But neither of these options, I am unable to run the script and trapped with below exception:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cspbGrp0']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a")) .click();

 Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 8139 Exception in thread
     "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element  
     (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.115)   (Driver info:
     chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The
     server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
     timeout: 5.06 seconds For documentation on this error, please visit:
     http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
     version: '2.42.0', revision:
     '5e824302019c86eae9c8c3ca9155e7307b410cf8', time: '2014-05-24
     09:48:41' System info: host: 'inl-279930-1', ip: '10.13.174.254',
     os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
     '1.7.0_55' Session ID: 04489825ed0cfc399afa1ffccb838870 Driver info:
     org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=XP,
     acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,
     chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\SUBRAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11808_15574},
     rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=40.0.2214.115,
     takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
     databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
     browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
     webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false,
     takesScreenshot=true}]     at
     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at
     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at
     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at
     org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
        at
     org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
        at
     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:596)
        at
     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:349)
        at
     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:446)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:357)  at
     org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:341)
        at roll_forward_test.cpe_progression.main(cpe_progression.java:147)
```

Could you help me to get this fixed, please.

Comment: Please how the _complete HTML document_ - and make sure you post the source document, not the DOM representation.

Comment: Have you tried it without the starting '.'?

Comment: @Mathias, Thank you for your quick reply! As suggested, I was trying to share the source code.

Since, it is our corporate application which can’t be shared with original data, I was trying to mask the sensitive information.

All the while, noticed that the element which got located and copied the XPATH while inspecting is not available in the Source Code; I am afraid that’s the cause of this `NoSuchElementException`

Can you kindly advise how I can inspect these kind of elements, please.

@Rac, as suggested tried it without “.”, but received the same exception.

Comment: It might be generated by Javascript, and thus not present in the source, but ... we don't know, since you gave hardly any information about this source - if you cannot share the link of this page or show the HTML, nobody can help you.

Comment: @Mathias, I've shared the complete source code of the webpage as a file in OneDrive. can you check and advise please.

http://1drv.ms/1C3PZqC

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to use css over xpath and I would usually write my own selectors.  Because it's in a table it can be a little tricky (meaning you may have to traverse from further up) but from the information on screen I'd go for something like:

```
//by href
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='../isp_track.asp?PARENT_MENU=Customer Order']"))
```

OR

```
//by class
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.cspbItm"))
```

Comment: Neither of the options didn't work; getting the same exception as above

Comment: If this doesn't work then you'll probably have to traverse from further up...driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[class='cspbItmA'] > a[href='../isp_track.asp?PARENT_MENU=Customer Order']"))

Comment: still the above code is unable to search and locate the link while running the script..as commented above, can you have a look on the comment that this element is not present in View Source of the page, however, able to inspect when I get into this page.

Complete View Source is archived in http://1drv.ms/1C3PZqC

Answer (score 0):

Issue identified and it is caused due to the element present inside an iFrame.

When switching to iFrame first, now able to locate the element.

Thank You,
Praveen